# Wrong shading of sphere

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, normals, shading

In my program I'm trying to import .obj files to OpenGL but if I calculate the normals and use them I get this wrong result: (The normals are calculated and to me seams all right but the result is not what I want)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7gXb.png)

```
 void CalcNormals(float * normals_ptr, float vertex_array[8000], int face_array[8000], int face_counter)
 {

   int counter = 0;

   float normalx = 0;
   float normaly = 0;
   float normalz = 0;

   float x0 = 0;
   float y0 = 0;
   float z0 = 0;

   float x1 = 0;
   float y1 = 0;
   float z1 = 0;

   float x2 = 0;
   float y2 = 0;
   float z2 = 0;


   while(counter < face_counter)
   {
     x0 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+0]*3+0];
     y0 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+0]*3+1];
     z0 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+0]*3+2];

     x1 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+1]*3+0];
     y1 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+1]*3+1];
     z1 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+1]*3+2];

     x2 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+2]*3+0];
     y2 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+2]*3+1];
     z2 = vertex_array[face_array[counter+2]*3+2];

     normalx = (y1-y0)*(z2-z0)-(z1-z0)*(y2-y0);
     normaly = (z1-z0)*(x2-x0)-(x1-x0)*(z2-z0);
     normalz = (x1-x0)*(y2-y0)-(y1-y0)*(x2-x0);


     normals_ptr[counter+0] = normalx;
     normals_ptr[counter+1] = normaly;
     normals_ptr[counter+2] = normalz;

     printf("TEST : %f   %f   %f\n", normalx, normaly, normalz);

     printf("FACES : %i\n", face_array[counter]);
     counter += 3;
   }

 }

void LoadObject(char * path, int size,
        float vector_array[80000], int * vector_counter, int * vector_loop,
        int face_array[80000], int * face_counter, int * face_loop,
        float normals_array[80000], int * normals_counter, int * normals_loop 
           )
{
  FILE * file;  
  char * fobj;
  fobj = malloc(size);
  int fpos = 0;

  file = fopen(path, "r");
  fread(fobj, 1, 8*size, file);

  int length_counter = 0;

  fpos = 0;
  void PrintFile()
  {
    int fpos_ = 0;
    while(fpos_ < size)
    {
      fpos_ += 1;
    }
  }


  fpos = 0;

    fpos += 7;
      while(fpos < size) //SOLANGE KEIN NEUES OBJEKT BEGINNT :
      {

    ///////////////////////////VERTEX-ARRAY////////////////////////////

    if(fobj[fpos+0] == 'v' && //WEN EIN NEUER VEKTOR BEGINNT :
       fobj[fpos+1] == ' '  )
    {
      fpos += 2;
      // WIRD DIESER IN DAS DAFÜR VORGESEHENE VEKTOR-ARRAY GESCHRIEBEN
      (*vector_loop) = 0;
      while( (*vector_loop) < 3 )
      {
        if(fobj[fpos] == '-') //wenn das vozeichen ein 'MINUS' ist wird ein buchstabe mehr genommen:
        {
          vector_array[(*vector_counter)] = strtof( &fobj[fpos], NULL );

          *vector_counter += 1;

          fpos += 10;
        }
        else // wenn kein vorzeichen vorhanden ist werden nur 8 buchstaben genommen :
        {
          vector_array[(*vector_counter)] = strtof( &(fobj[fpos]), NULL );

          (*vector_counter) += 1;

          fpos += 9;
        }
        (*vector_loop) += 1;
      }

    }

    ////////////////////////NORMALS-ARRAY///////////////////////////


    else if(fobj[fpos+0] == 'v' && //WEN EIN NEUER NORMAL-VEKTOR BEGINNT :
        fobj[fpos+1] == 'n' &&
        fobj[fpos+2] == ' '  )
    {
      fpos += 3;
      // WIRD DIESER IN DAS DAFÜR VORGESEHENE NORMALS-ARRAY GESCHRIEBEN
      (*normals_loop) = 0;
      while( (*normals_loop) < 3 )
      {
        if(fobj[fpos] == '-') //wenn das vozeichen ein 'MINUS' ist wird ein buchstabe mehr genommen:
        {
          //normals_array[(*normals_counter)] = strtof( &fobj[fpos], NULL );

          (*normals_counter) += 1;

          fpos += 10;
        }
        else // wenn kein vorzeichen vorhanden ist werden nur 8 buchstaben genommen :
        {
          //normals_array[(*normals_counter)] = strtof( &(fobj[fpos]), NULL );

          (*normals_counter) += 1;

          fpos += 9;
        }
        (*normals_loop) += 1;
      }
    }


    ////////////////////////////FACE-ARRAY///////////////////////////////

    else if(fobj[fpos+0] == 'f' &&  //wenn ein 'FACE' erkannt wird :
        fobj[fpos+1] == ' '  )
    {
      fpos += 2; //damit das 'f ' nicht mit in das Auslesen der 'FACES' einfiest.

      *face_loop = 0;
      while((*face_loop) < 3)
      {
        //wird der 1. wert in das face_array geschrieben :
        face_array[(*face_counter)] = (strtol(&fobj[fpos], NULL, 10)-1);
        printf("1.WERT : %i\n", face_array[*face_counter]);
        //wird nach einem Leerzeichen oder einem NL-Zeichen gesucht :
        length_counter = 0; //davor wird die aktuelle länge zurückgesetzt damit nicht an der falschen stelle gesucht wird.
        while(fobj[fpos+length_counter] != ' ' && fobj[fpos+length_counter] != '\n')
        {
          length_counter += 1;
        }
        fpos += length_counter+1; // '+1' weil das Leerzeichen/NL-Zeichen übersprungen werden muss da sonst die aktuelle länge = 0 ist.
        (*face_counter) += 1;
       (*face_loop)+= 1;
      }
     (*face_loop)= 0;

    }

    else // wenn kein neuer vektor beginnt : 
    {
      fpos += 1;
    }
      }
}



void InitOpt()
{

  // LIGHTING
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
  //glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_FALSE);


  glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient_color);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse_color);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular_color);

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spot_direction);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

  glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 3);
  glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0);
  glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 360);

  printf("LIGHTING : %i\n", glIsEnabled(GL_LIGHTING));
  printf("LIGHT0 : %i\n", glIsEnabled(GL_LIGHT0));

  // COLORING
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);

  // ENABLE CLIENTSTATES FOR CALLING MULTIBLE VALUES AT ONCE
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // ENABLE GL_VERTEX_ARRAY
  glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); // ENABLE GL_NORMAL_ARRAY


  // MATERIAL

  //glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

  glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
  glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, std_color_gray);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, std_color_gray);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, std_color_black);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specular_color);
  glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 128);



}

void RenderScene()
{



    KeyFunction();
    RotateCam(alpha_angle, beta_angle);

    spot_direction[0] = centerX-eyeX;
    spot_direction[1] = centerY-eyeY;
    spot_direction[2] = centerZ-eyeZ;

    light_position[0] = eyeX;
    light_position[1] = eyeY;
    light_position[2] = eyeZ;

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spot_direction);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90, aspect, near, far); //SET PERSPECTIVE

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, //SET CAMERA POSITION
          centerX, centerY, centerZ,
          upX, upY, upZ);



    // bougth clientstates have to be enabled

    int counter = 0;

    /*
    animation0 += (2*3.1415926535)/36;
    if(animation0 >= (2*3.1415923535) )
    {
      animation0 = 0;
    }
    */

    animation1 += 0.5;
    if(animation1 >= 360)
    {
      animation1 = 0;
    }


    //glRotatef(animation1, 0, 0, 1);


      glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector_array_p0); //SET POINTER TO THE GL_VERTEX_ARRAY (p0)
      glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals_array_p0); //SET NORMALS ARRAY (p1)
      glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, face_counter_p0, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, face_array_p0); //DRAWS 'KURBELWELLE'


    /*
    glTranslatef(0.7, 0, -0.5);
    glRotatef(animation1*(-1), 0, 0, 1);

      glRotatef(cos(grad*animation1)*( 16), 0, 0, 1);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector_array_p1); //SET POINTER TO THE GL_VERTEX_ARRAY (p1)
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals_array_p1); //SET NORMALS ARRAY (p1)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, face_counter_p1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, face_array_p1); //DRAWS 'ZYLINDER 0'

      glRotatef(cos(grad*animation1)*(-16), 0, 0, 1);

        glTranslatef(cos(grad*animation1)*(-0.7), 2.5, 0);

          glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector_array_p2); //SET POINTER TO THE GL_VERTEX_ARRAY (p2)
          glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals_array_p2); //SET NORMALS ARRAY (p2)
          glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, face_counter_p2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, face_array_p2); //DRAWS 'ZYLINDER-KOPF 0'

        glTranslatef(cos(grad*animation1)*( 0.7), -2.5, 0);

    glRotatef(animation1, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-0.7, 0, 0.5);


    glTranslatef(-0.7, 0, 0.5);
    glRotatef(animation1*(-1), 0, 0, 1);

      glRotatef(cos(grad*animation1)*(-16), 0, 0, 1);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector_array_p1); //SET POINTER TO THE GL_VERTEX_ARRAY (p1)
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals_array_p1); //SET NORMALS ARRAY (p1)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, face_counter_p1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, face_array_p1); //DRAWS 'ZYLINDER 1'

      glRotatef(cos(grad*animation1)*( 16), 0, 0, 1);

        glTranslatef(cos(grad*animation1)*( 0.7), 2.5, 0);

          glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector_array_p2); //SET POINTER TO THE GL_VERTEX_ARRAY (p2)
          glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals_array_p2); //SET NORMALS ARRAY (p2)
          glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, face_counter_p2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, face_array_p2); //DRAWS 'ZYLINDER-KOPF 1'

        glTranslatef(cos(grad*animation1)*(-0.7), -2.5, 0);
     */


    while( time_mark > clock() )
    {
          ;
    }
    if( time_mark <= clock() )
    {
      time_mark = clock() + (CLOCKS_PER_SEC*0.01);
      SwapBuffers();
    }
}

void CreateWindow()
{
  glutInitWindowSize(960, 540);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
  window_id = glutCreateWindow("FACE");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{ 
  float time = (float) clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("TRY ONE : ........................…\n.............................\n\n");
  printf("LOADING...\n");

  LoadObject("/home/nikolaij/Schreibtisch/MOTOR/pyramide.obj", 800000,
         vector_array_p0, &vector_counter_p0, &vector_loop_p0,
         face_array_p0, &face_counter_p0, &face_loop_p0,
         normals_array_p0, &normals_counter_p0, &normals_loop_p0
        );

  CalcNormals(normals_array_p0, vector_array_p0, face_array_p0, face_counter_p0);

  /*
  LoadObject("/home/nikolaij/Schreibtisch/MOTOR/zylinder.obj", 800000,
         vector_array_p1, &vector_counter_p1, &vector_loop_p1,
         face_array_p1, &face_counter_p1, &face_loop_p1,
         normals_array_p1, &normals_counter_p1, &normals_loop_p1
        );

  LoadObject("/home/nikolaij/Schreibtisch/MOTOR/zylinder_kopf.obj", 800000,
         vector_array_p2, &vector_counter_p2, &vector_loop_p2,
         face_array_p2, &face_counter_p2, &face_loop_p2,
         normals_array_p2, &normals_counter_p2, &normals_loop_p2
        );
  */
  printf("TIME : %f   FACES : %i\n", (float) clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC - time, face_counter_p1 + face_counter_p2);
  printf("INITIALISATION\n");

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  CreateWindow();

  printf("InitOpt\n");
  InitOpt();

  //printf("LOADING SHADER\n");
  //UseShader("/home/nikolaij/Schreibtisch/Drunken_Monkey/Shader/simple_shader.frag", 63);
  //printf("END\n");

  glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
  glutIdleFunc(RenderScene);

  glutReshapeFunc(ReshapeFunc);

  glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPressed);
  glutKeyboardUpFunc(KeyReleased);

  glutPassiveMotionFunc(MotionFunc);

  printf("FINISHED\n");

  glutMainLoop();

  return(0);
}
```

Simple .obj file (cube):

```
# Blender v2.76 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Cube.004_Cube.005
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
s off
f 4//1 3//1 1//1
f 8//2 7//2 3//2
f 6//3 5//3 7//3
f 2//4 1//4 5//4
f 3//5 7//5 5//5
f 8//6 4//6 2//6
f 2//1 4//1 1//1
f 4//2 8//2 3//2
f 8//3 6//3 7//3
f 6//4 2//4 5//4
f 1//5 3//5 5//5
f 6//6 8//6 2//6
```

This is a part of my code. (Its not really  clean...)

Comment: What *is* the result you want?

Comment: I don't think you normalize your normals at least

Comment: I want a perfectly shades sphere(a part  of it)

Comment: And please cut the code example down to the necessary parts only.

Comment: @noName: Your code doesn't really make sense. You seem to calculate a normal per face and not per vertex, with comepltely different indices as the vertex indices by the face, and seem to expect OpenGL to magically sort out the maching data per vertex.

Comment: Its based on a obj file Im going to add a simple one to the question and yes, Im calculating the normals per face....

Comment: (for saving memory: if one coord is used twice it calls the coordinate by an index so the fases are defined like this : face one = index : 0, 1, 2 face two = inde: 1, 2, 3 so we dont have to write the same coord twice in the .obj file)

Comment: You are calculating one normal per face. OpenGL requires you to have one normal per vertex. So you will have to calculate normals for each vertex from the weighted normals of the adjacent faces.

Comment: Tip: If you want to save memory normals can often be fitted in just a byte per axis.

Comment: I see that you are calculating the normals on your own, but just saying: Blender and other modeling program can easily export them for you. And if you use Assimp, it can even generate the normals for you. In fact your .obj file has them in there, so why are you calculating them?

Comment: I calculate them because the cube is tringulated and so it should have 12 face normals

Comment: and I had some test and id seams like glNormalPointer takes face normals but if im wrong please correct me

Comment: glNormalPointer always takes vertex normals, not face normals. Just give all vertices in the same face the same normal. You might have to duplicate some of the vertices for that.

Comment: I did this now correctly but i thin k my normals-array if false sorted, do you know how it has to be sorted ?